# Error getting data from Firebase Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase

Having a problem here with firebase which I can't figure out. Trying to get data from Firebase and load it up in a UITableView but seem to be having an issue converting the data from firebase into an array. Getting the following error message :

'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key -KyP-yzMcrvb7Z-PdAp0.'

Now I can print out the dummy data from the 'dic' which is shown here: 
["-KyP-yzMcrvb7Z-PdAp0": asdasd, "-KyP-wrMpuHqLQIMSgXI": dsad]. That is the value of the FB login user into firebase so I assume its having a problem converting that?

Here is my model class :
import UIKit

class Rentals: NSObject {

```
var title: String?
var rentalType: String?
var dateAval: String?
var location: String?
var price: String?
var bond: String?
var pets: String?
var descripton: String?
```

}

This is my TableViewVC code to grab the data from Firebase and chuck it in the array:

class TableViewVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

```
@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!
var rentalsArr = [Rentals]()
var databaseRef:DatabaseReference?
var handle: UInt!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
    fetchRentalData()

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->  UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = rentalsArr[indexPath.row].title
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return rentalsArr.count
}

func fetchRentalData(){

    handle = databaseRef?.child("Rentals").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snap) in
        if let dic = snap.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            print("******\(dic)")
            let rentals = Rentals()

            rentals.setValuesForKeys(dic)
            self.rentalsArr.append(rentals)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.myTableView.reloadData()
            }




        }
    })



}
```

}

I have spent many hours trying to get this going so any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: What were you expecting `rentals.setValuesForKeys(dic)` to do? i mean, clearly dict has no data that relates to any property in your definition of `Rentals` so I'm confused. Can you clarify?

Comment: Hi Caio, thanks for the reply. My understanding was that i'm doing a database lookup under the child 'Rentals' and then creating a dictionary (dic) and casting this to type [String: AnyObject] . This relates to the firebase dba as the root is of type string ("Rentals") and the key is array so casting this to AnyObject. Im then trying to add the string values from within this object into the rentals array I created of type Rentals. I am pretty new to all this so perhaps I have got this incorrect? Cheers

Comment: Let me rephrase. Given the dict  ["-KyP-yzMcrvb7Z-PdAp0": asdasd, "-KyP-wrMpuHqLQIMSgXI": dsad] how would you expect the properties of the Rentals object to be set? What would be each property's value?

Comment: Hmm I think I may have to look into this further..I was under the impression the key was the facebook login auth and the value would be the object (a set of arrays contained) - but that is incorrect and the key is associated with the child within firebase 'Rentals'... At first glance i imagine this needs to be [String: String] then to work...Thanks for pointing me in the right direction Caio appreciate it.

Comment: Actually thinking about it I think that Rentals model needs to be an Object and each of the vars need to be of type [String:String] to catch this properly. Will check this out when I get back to my mac.

Comment: The dict will be a [String: AnyObject] but you need to know what keys and values you expect to find.

Comment: I mean, your crash happens because you are trying to do KVO with keys that do not have a matching property in the dir. I´d avise to manually get each property from the dir, cast it to the expected type and then set it on the   Rentals object.